# Почему цикл for прекращает работу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне требуется из списка `term_list`, так сказать, вырезать все числа, но по какой то причине, после того как я получаю первое число и перемещаю его в отдельный список, итерация циклов прекращается, прекращается она на знаке `+`, почему так происходит?

```
term_list =  ['2', '2', '+', '2', '2', '+', '2', '2']
Input_line_numbers = []

for n in term_list:
    print('   Я итерация цикла ')
    if n in ("+"):
        print('\n         Я ариф.действия: ',n)
        index = term_list.index(n)
        print('       Я индекс ариф.действия: ',index)
        Input_line_numbers.append(''.join(term_list[0:index]))
        print('       Я список чисел строки ввода: ',Input_line_numbers)
        del term_list[0:index+1]
        print('       Я список строки ввода: ',term_list,'\n')
        
print('\n\nЯ список строки ввода: ',term_list)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это происходит из-за то что вы удаляете элементы массив в цикле

```
for n in term_list:
```

поменяйте

```
for n in term_list.copy():
```

Comment: Когда ж они перестанут это делать? Чуть не каждый день такое )

Comment: @CrasyElf можно создать вопрос и дать на него развёрнутый ответ, а остальные закрывать как дубликаты

Comment: Да надо бы уже какой-то FAQ составить для новичков и всех на него отправлять первым делом. Но у меня лично и без того дел )